# How to monitor CPU and memory usage during an integration test in Flutter

Tags: flutter, profiling

I would like to get CPU and memory usage data during an integration test in Flutter. I'm using the `integration_test` library to run my tests. I managed to read frame render times using the `SchedulerBinding` class, but I have no idea how to do this with CPU and memory. My goal is to generate a `.csv` file with this data.

According to the Flutter docs, it is possible to do this using `profiling_summarizer.dart`. I don't know how to get `Timeline` and then `TimelineEvents`. The method [here](https://www.bookstack.cn/read/flutter-cookbook/47e10a27d0a97006.md) doesn't seem to work with `integration_test` instead of `flutter_driver`. Should I use `flutter_driver` for my tests or is there a way to do it with `integration_test`?

Here is a snippet I've tried:

```dart
void main() async {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  FlutterDriver flutterDriver =
      await FlutterDriver.connect();

  await flutterDriver.startTracing();

  final SchedulerBinding schedulerBinding = SchedulerBinding.instance;
  schedulerBinding.addTimingsCallback((timings) {
    for (final timing in timings) {
      print('${timing.frameNumber}, ${timing.totalSpan.inMilliseconds};');
    }
  });

  // testing
 
  Timeline timeline = await flutterDriver.stopTracingAndDownloadTimeline();
  await TimelineSummary.summarize(timeline)
      .writeTimelineToFile("main", pretty: true);
}
```